# Image and text inline and stacked for responsive

Tags: image, text, inline, responsive, banner

It has been some time since I really coded, and my mind just can't get this (easy) problem. I need a banner at the top of a page that has an image on the right and text on the left that appears to be one long image with the BG blending with the actual image. I also need the image to stack on top of the text at smaller screen sizes. I ma having trouble with a ton of stuff. getting the text to be vertically aligned with the image, getting the text div to be equal height as the image, and most importantly getting the 2 to stack properly. I need the image to resize and fill 100% when they stack and the text to center under the image. Any help would be great. This is a very simple problem, i know, and I am sure i have a bunch of redundant or unnecessary stuff in here...

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  align-content:center;
  text-align:center

}

.column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    padding: 0px;
 vertical-align:middle; 
 min-width: 250px;
 align-content:center
}

.column1 {
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;  
 max-width: 65% ;
 min-width: 250px;
  align-content:center

}

.column1 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

img {
width:100%;
height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .column1 .column2 { display: block; }
}
/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .column1 {
        width: 100%; height: auto
    }
    
    .column2 {
        width: 100%; background:#ffffff
    }
 
}

 @media screen and (min-width: 501px)  {
  
  .row {
     background:#f2f1eb
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=east" alt="Dog" style="width:100%; align-content:center; vertical-align:middle">
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div style="width:100%; vertical-align:middle"><p align="center" style="vertical-align:middle">We love having your family members as part of our community. </p> </div>
  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: You want the image and the text to be aligned at large resolutions and stacked at small ones?

Comment: Correct, sorry for my delayed response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand correctly what you want to achieve (since you did no answer my question) but if you want the image and the text to be aligned at large resolutions and stacked at small ones:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: #efefef;
}

.column1 {
  width: 35%;
  min-width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.column2 {
  width: 65%;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font: 14px/1.5 arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.column1 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .column1, .column2 {width: 100%}
  .column1 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .text {
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">
    <p class="text">We love having your family members as part of our community.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=east" alt="Dog" style="width:100%; align-content:center; vertical-align:middle">
  </div>
</div>
```